# Using jQuery, how do you get the text from an anchor link after clicking the following anchor link?

Tags: jquery, anchor

Using jquery I am trying to grab the .text() from an anchor link after clicking a link immediately following the first anchor link. There is no class on either of the two links however there is one for the ordered list. The structure is:

`<ol id="articles">
<li>Author name <a href="">Title of article</a> | <a href="" id="button1">link B</a></li>
<li>Second author name <a href="">Second title of article</a> | <a href="">link C</a></li>
</ol>`

Result would be:
Clicking on "link B" the alert would say, "Title of article"
Clicking on "link C" the alert would say, "Second title of article"

What I have so far is:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#articles a").click(function(){
       var text = $(this).text();
       alert(text);
    });
});`

But this just gives me the text for the linked clicked. I need the text of the link prior to the clicked link. Any suggestions to get me on the right path?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last `a` all `li` using `#articles li a:last-child` and select previous `a` using [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).  Browse through jQuery's methods for [traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) the DOM to see what operations are made available for you to use.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#articles li a:last-child").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).prev('a').text();
    alert(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="articles">
  <li>Author name <a href="">Title of article</a> | <a href="" id="button1">link B</a>
  </li>
  <li>Second author name <a href="">Second title of article</a> | <a href="">link C</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```